# DetourCreateProcessWithDllEx replacement

Tags: hook, detours

I am trying to hook detours dll into my application it works but my application launches another exe. I can't attach to that exe because it says launch previous application and closes.

What I am trying to ask is, is there something in detours API that allows me to hook onto a process?

Comment: I probably can't answer your question anyway, but I certainly didn't get this part: "because it says launch previous application and closes". What exactly happens and what are the messages you get, if any?

Comment: It just uses a mutex and says need to run other application. Its a launcher an exe that says run launcher first.